# Confused about maximum connections in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, connections, database-internals, max-connections, connection-pooling

I am building a web application and I using PostgreSQL as the database management system.

The following page details the maximum connections setting:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-connection.html.

I read about tuning on the following page

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

and it mentions

> Generally, PostgreSQL on good hardware can support a few hundred connections.

**Question**

I am confused about what defines a "connection". Many web sites have thousands or more users and it seems if it can only support a few hundred connections at once, then significant horizontal scaling would be required.  Are connections very short?...Meaning, if a user loads a page and it queries the database, does it open and close a connection before and after?

Comment: What language are you writing your website in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a web application you use a connection pool that establishes a fixed amount of *database* connections that are then shared between all sessions in your web applications.

Even when a web application has thousands of *concurrent* users, it might only need as much as 50 database connections (if the connection pooling is done right).

> Meaning, if a user loads a page and it queries the database, does it open and close a connection before and after?

No, you shouldn't do that. Opening and closing connections is a relatively expensive operation. The connection pool will typically keep the connections open - at least for a defined amount of time. Your application takes connections from the *pool* and returns them to the pool.

Comment: May pay off to explain about how a web site is hosted cgi/fastcgi, persistence. etc. A connection pool may not make sense at all if you don't understand persistence.